# Adding "active" class to seperate menu with unslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, unslider

ello!

To the point:
https://jsfiddle.net/andeh/adjgnjyb/2/

```
<div class="slider">
<ul>
    <li class="slide slide1">
        slide 1
    </li>
    <li class="slide slide2">
        slide 2
    </li>
    <li class="slide slide3">
        slide 3
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<nav class="menu">
<ul>
    <li id="slide1">item1</li>
    <li id="slide2">item2</li>
    <li id="slide3">item3</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I want to get the menu item to have an 'active' class when the "slide" is on the specified page...

i.e. 
The page has a full page slider with 3 sections on it, all relating to the menu items. When it goes from say "about us" to "join our team" it will highlight the related menu item...

Ive created a jsfiddle so people know what im getting at, as i made it on local. if any one could help, that would be great!

Comment: It looks like it already does. According to your jsfiddle anyway.

Comment: That adds an active class to the slide itself, i want the active class on the menu outside of the slides.

So essentially:
Where active slide has class "slide$", find nav with id of "slide$" > add class "active" - Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unslider also gives you option to attach events to it, though these events are synchronous, so don't add blocking code in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/adjgnjyb/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var slider = $('.slider').unslider({
    autoplay: true,
    delay: 5000
});
slider.on('unslider.change', function(event, index, slide) {
   $("#slide1, #slide2, #slide3").removeClass("active")
   $("#slide" + (index + 1)).addClass("active")
});
});
```